# VBA Dictionary Not Deleting Key

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, collections

I'm trying to replace an old dictionary value with a new collection.  I cannot figure out why the key that is being found is not getting deleted.  I changed the .CompareMode to TextCompare but still cannot successfully delete the string.  Updating the value of the dictionary didn't work either, so I tried to remove then add again.  [Reference](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

**How can I remove and add back (or update) the key/value pair of the dictionary?**

```
collStr = "testvalue"
c.Add (collStr)

If dict.Exists(Key) Then
   dict.Remove Key         '<- This should remove but still appearing in 'Watches' dictionary
If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
   dict(Key) = c           '<- Trying to replace only dictionary value with new collection
   'dict.Add Key, c
End If
```

[image: before-removing-key]

[image: after-removing-key]

Comment: `Set dict(Key) = c` since you're setting an object reference (collection).

Comment: If you put a watch on a dictionary then just referring to the key in the Watch window can re-add the key, so be wary of what you see when using a Watch on a dictionary... Previously -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896394/dictionary-exists-returning-different-values-for-variable-and-constant-key/48896896#48896896

Comment: @KostasK. if you give as answer, I will accept then delete this comment